# Requesting XML returns a string with many carriage returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.behindthename.com/api/lookup.php?name=olga&key=li758582', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log (body);
  }
})
```

I'm trying to fetch an XML file from an api using node.js.
When I fetch it using the above code with this [Request Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) I get XML with many unnecessary "\r" like so:

```
\r<response>\r<name_detail>\r<name>Oľga</name>\r<gender>f</gender>
```

When I go to the URL with my browser it has no extra line returns at all.

This is what I see on my browser:

[image]

Is it possible to fetch just the source XML with node.js? Also, is there a smarter way to fetch XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. that article has an excellent guide on how exactly to do it.
http://antrikshy.com/blog/fetch-xml-url-convert-to-json-nodejs